# How to set up connection pooling in an OSGi bundle?

Tags: db2, osgi, connection-pooling

After many years of developing web applications for the Websphere platform, I have recently been looking at OSGi especially in connection with the RAP (RichAjayPlatform) project.

In the past, I have been able to access connection pools defined in the EAR using JNDI lookups.

How do you create connection pools and access them in an OSGi environment? I have created a DB2 bundle containing the jdbc drivers but I'm not sure how to create the pool. Previously, this was a configuration in the EAR and Websphere handled it.

Are there any examples, tutorials out there?

Comment: Are you looking to deploy into WebSphere Application Server? If so all the DataSources are available in the service registry. You can look them up using the javax.sql.DataSource interface type and use the osgi.jndi.service.name service property which will be set to the name of the object in global jndi.

Comment: @Alasdair - Thanks! Yes, the app will be deployed to WAS. Should I build a target definition using the WAS installation so I can test? Or what would you suggest?
BTW - your comment is really an answer. I think you should copy it into a new answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing "built in" to OSGi to do connection pooling of course, but it is very simple to implement.

First, your client code should access the database via a service, probably of type `javax.sql.DataSource` (I recommend using Declarative Services to inject this into your component).

Then you need a bundle that will create a connection pool using a specific driver and register the `DataSource` service(s). I would also build this using Declarative Services, wrapping the Apache Commons DBCP library.

Comment: This is the approach I took with setting up JPA. There's DriverDataSource in OpenJPA that works great for creating a DataSource based on a driver.

Comment: Is there any example code of how to do this with dbcp? I have found org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource which is probably what we want to register as an OSGi service. There is also an example for it outside of OSGi http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/doc/PoolingDataSourceExample.java?view=markup

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to register the connection pool manager as an OSGi service. If you add in the Apache Aries JNDI bundle, all of your services will also be exposed via JNDI. Some connection pool managers don't play well in OSGi because of classloader issues but having the driver embedded in the same bundle that configures the connection pool can often get around those.

I've only set this up using JPA + JNDI but the steps I would take with creating and exporting a connection pool would be something like this:

1. Manually create a connection pool (c3p0, dbcp, etc) in the bundle activator.
2. Register the connection pool as a service with the bundle context.
3. In the services that need a connection, get a reference to the connection pool (I use declarative services) and get a connection from the pool.